# Use 2 methods 1. Check if object exists 2. Add object

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I was wondering how do I go about to create 2 methods,
 1. Which does the checking, if the object already exists within the array (based on one of the parameters).
 2. Secondly add a method which allows the user / me to add objects into the array when the previous (1st method) returns false.

Here is my try:

```
public class Book {
    String name;
    int isbn;


    public Book(String e, int iNr) throws LibraryException{
        if(e.equals("")){
            throw new LibraryException("Blank / empty name is not allowed!");
        }

        else if(iNr < 1 || iNr > 9000){
            throw new LibraryException("The isbn number is outside the allowed range (1 - 9000)! ");
        }
        setName(e);
        setIsbn(iNr);
    }


    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(obj instanceof Book){
            isbn = (isbn)obj;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    public String getName() {
        if(name == null || name == ""){
            System.out.print("Does not exist!");
        }
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getIsbn() {
        if(isbn < 0){
            System.out.print("ISBN (LIBRI) EXCEPTION TO BE ADDED!");
        }
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Library
{
    String name;
    Book[] books;
    int nrBooks = 0;

    public Library(String name, int nrBooks) throws LibraryException {  
        if(name.equals("")){
            throw new LibraryException("Blank names is not allowed");
        }

        if(nrBooks < 500){
            throw new LibraryException("The number of books needs to be greater than 500!");
        }

        this.name = name;
        this.nrBooks = nrBooks;
        this.books = new Book[nrBooks];

    }


    public void addBook(Book book) throws LibraryException {
         if(indexOf(book) == -1){
                if(nrBooks < books.length)
                    books[nrBooks++] = book;

         }
    }
    private int indexOf(Book book)throws LibraryException {

        if(nrBooks < Book[].length){

        }


        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) throws LibraryException{
        Library b = new Library("Sami Frasheri", 700);
        b.addBook(new Book("Paul Colhen - Alchemist", 1));
        b.addBook(new Book("Paul Colhen - Winners Stand ALone", 2));
        b.addBook(new Book("Paul Colhen - The river Piedra I sat and I cried", 3));

        System.out.print(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: you never use the result of `indexOf(book book)` in your code:

public void addbook(book book) throws LibraryException {
        if(indexOf(book) == -1){
            if(nrbooks < books.length){
                books[nrbooks++] = book;
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Java Convention says that class should start with Uppercase Letter. So instead of book use Book.

Comment: Could you help me out by fixing that part of my code, I am new to Java so while I do understand what you mean I can't see what you want me to do. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to compare the ISBN in your `equals(Object)` method as well as the (presumably?) name

Comment: @AbhishekSingh I tried to translate variables to English language so you guys would have an easier time, seems I miss-typed that.. I'll update it

Comment: @JonK Tbh I need to do that excactly as you say, however I am puzzled as I got these methods together by searching all around on Google and learning while coding (static Arrays are hard to deal with). So could you please specify more on what I need to do or if you got spare time actually fix that part of my code with an explanation (as I want to understand rather than just get it done). Thanks a bunch anyways

Answer (score 0):

Tried [ArrayList In Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)?.

They will be able to solve almost all of the problems you are facing. Have a look at `contains` and `add`.

**Please Note**, you must override the `hashCode` and `equals` method of your Book object for it to work effectively.

Comment: I love ArrayList's however, I am new to Java and got an Exam, I love the language and did manage to learn all the rest that we need to, I'm stuck on this and he specifically asked for Arrays, I'm afraid I'm not allowed to use ArrayLists... otherwise I would, they are just brilliant.. that's why I need to figure this out with normal Arrays (static)

Comment: SO does not help people in assignment or tests

Comment: I am trying to learn Java, I am not asking for you to do my homework, as you can clearly see I did quiet a lot on my own from what I learned and researched, but I'm stuck here as I don't have the knowledge you people do. You mean to tell me SO is for 30+ age or?

Comment: Start with posting the related code and line which causes problem and what problem is caused exactly ? Question seems incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for understanding and I will just let me know what needs to be written, I mean I did highlight the 2 methods I need help with and what I want to accomplish. If anything more or if the actual information needs to be changed, I'll gladly do it. Thanks

Comment: Start with adding main method. There are too many mistakes in your question

Comment: I got the main method, I just did not post the whole of my 3 classes, as the rest works except these 2 methods,  I guess I'll update my code and post the rest of what I have

Comment: There updated the whole code, hopefully now it is correct

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use an ArrayList of Book. It will solve all of your problems.

```
  public class Library {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Book> books;
    private int maxNumberOfBooks;

    public Library(String name, int maxNumberOfBooks) {
        this.name = name;
        this.maxNumberOfBooks = maxNumberOfBooks;
        this.books = new ArrayList<Book>();
    }


    public void addBook(Book book) {
        if (!books.contains(book)) {
            books.add(book);
        }
    }

}
```

If you need to check both parameters, then do something like:

```
public void addBook(Book book) {
    for (Book b : books) {
        if (b.getName().equals(book.getName())) {
            return; // another book has the same name
        }
        if (b.getIsbn() == book.getIsbn()) {
            return; // another book has the same ISBN
        }
    }
    books.add(book);
}
```

Comment: will not work if equals and hashCode of Book is not overridden.

Comment: What do you mean by that " equals andhashCode of book is not overriden " ?

Answer (score 0):

The size of an array can't be modified. If you want to add an element, you have to instantiate a new array.

```
public void addBook(Book book) {
    int oldN = books.length;
    books = Arrays.copyOf(books, oldN + 1);
    books[oldN] = book;
    return books;
}
```

This function could replace indexOf(). It looks for the element in your array.

```
private boolean contains(Book book) {
    for (Book b : books) {
        if (b != null && book.equals(b))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
     public void addBook(Book book) throws LibraryException {
             if(indexOf(book) == -1){//book does not exist
                    if(nrBooks < (books.length-1)){
                        books[nrBooks] = book;
                        ++nrBooks;
                    } else {
                        throw new LibraryException("Not space for more books.");
                    }
             }
        }


     private int indexOf(Book book)throws LibraryException {
         for(int i=0;i<books.lenght;++i){
            if(books[i].getName().equals(book.getName()) && books[i].getIsbn==book.getIsbn){
              return i;
            }//if
         }//for
      //else
      return -1;
     }
```